# How to access local image URL in a json file

Tags: json, react-native

I have problem in accessing the local image url in a json file. Below are all the approaches I have tried but none of them works.

```
// json
{
    "image": "./images/example.jpg",
}

// React Native
import data from './data.json';

const URL =  JSON.stringify(data.image)   
<Image source = {{uri: URL } style = {{ width: 98, height: 22 }} />    // Image not showing

const URL = data.image
<Image source = {{uri: URL } style = {{ width: 98, height: 22 }} />    // Image not showing
```

Image is not showing in the above approaches.

I also tried with require as following:

```
// json
{
    "image": "example.jpg",
}

const item =  data.image   
<Image source = {require( './images/' +  item)} style = {{ width: 98, height: 22 }} />

const item =  JSON.stringify(data.image) 
<Image source = {require( './images/' +  item)} style = {{ width: 98, height: 22 }} />
```

The above shows an error of requires only take string literal argument, which is weird to me because the following code actually works.

```
const item = 'example.jpg'
<Image source = {require( './images/' +  item)} style = {{ width: 98, height: 22 }} />
```

I been searching on the internet for hours and could not find a solution to it. Can someone show me an correct example to access the local json data? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use variables in require. All require must be statically analyzable. That means you always have to write require('/path/to/file'). You can try something like

```
const images = {
    profile: {
        profile: require('./profile/profile.png'),
        comments: require('./profile/comments.png'),
    },
    image1: require('./image1.jpg'),
    image2: require('./image2.jpg'),
};

export default images;
import Images from './img/index';

render() {
    <Image source={Images.profile.comments} />
}
```

You can see more about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481)

> We intentionally don't support dynamically generated image names
>   because it makes it very hard to manage assets over time, just like
>   how you wouldn't want to do
>
> var MyComponent = require('./' + libName + typeOfComponent);
>
> or something like that. Dynamic image name generation like this also
>   won't work with the new dynamic asset managing system we're rolling
>   out which let's you add and update assets on the fly with just cmd+R
>   (no more need to add to Xcode and recompile).

Comment: This helped me I was doing something similar with react

Comment: You are talking about a JS component not a json file!

Answer (score 1):

JSON File:

```
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Toyota Corolla XLI \\Hatchback Automatic",
"details": "4 seater, diesel",
"picture": "./static/images/XLI.jpg",
"overcharge": "PKR 179 per excess km",
"weekday": "PKR 190/hr",
"weekend": "PKR 287/hr",
"car_type": "SUV"
```

},

And then add inyour .js file like this:

```
{PostData.map((postDetail, index) => {
                return (
                  <Link href="details">
                    <Card className="carditem">
                      <Card.Body style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                        <Row>
                          <Col xs="12" sm="4">
                            <img
                              src={postDetail.picture}
                              class="d-block"
                              height="170"
                            />
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

keep your json in a .js file and do as follows...

```
import avg from "./Components/Avenger-bg1.jpg";
import bts from "./Components/BTS-bg1.jpg";
import dis from "./Components/Disney-bg1.jpg";
import hp from "./Components/HP-bg1.jpg";
import crn from "./Components/BTS-bg1.jpg";
export const theme=[
  {
    "theme_name": "AVENGERS",
    "path": avg
  },
  {
    "theme_name": "BTS",
    "path": bts
  },
  {
    "theme_name": "DISNEY",
    "path": dis
  },
  {
    "theme_name": "HP",
    "path": hp
  },
  {
    "theme_name": "CROWN",
    "path": crn
  }
]
```

Import all the image paths required and assign those variables inside json
not the path directly.

Comment: It means that I can not have an external json file? No way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use require keyword. Let's say we have the following record from a data.json file.

```
{
    "id": 118,
    "channelName": "Nintendo Life",
    "videoName": "The 26 Best Game Boy Advance (GBA) Games of All Time",
    "videoId": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhK3W_3CW7w ",
    "views": 2232114,
    "channelThumbnail": "/channels/nintendo-life.jpg",
    "videoThumbnail": "./image/26-best-games.jpg"
  },
```

just move your image folder to the Public folder then import like

import data from './image/data.json'

then map this data with a built-in javascript function

data && data.map(item=>

##### {item.channelName}

)and so on